# How to convert python files to executables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

I have been looking all over for this, but they all seem to complicated! I want to convert a python 33 file to an executable so I can send give it to someone who hasn't got python.

Is there an online application that does it for you? Or a really simple converter that you download?

Simple answers please?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) to convert a Python 3.3 file to an executable.

Comment: Will try this. 
Thanks, btw any tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `py2exe`

For the more information http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: According to the info on the py2exe page linked, that it can only handle up to Python 3.1, not 3.3.